# Breaking up a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of values stored in SortedLat, where SortedLat is a list of 74 sublists, and each sublist has its first element be a string. As you can see I am trying to create the first column for a table with these strings.

```
TableOfValues1 = Prepend[q, {"B1", "B2"}]
TableOfValues2 = 
 MapThread[
  Prepend, {TableOfValues1, {"", 
    Partition[Table[SortedLat[[m]][[1]], {m, 1, 74}], 1]}}]
```

B1,B2 are just lists of 74 numbers.

I realize the problem with the code is probably that

```
Partition[Table[SortedLat[[m]][[1]],{m,1,74}],1]}}]
```

gives me a list of 74 strings instead of 74 separate strings. Therefore it gives the error that the dimensions don't match. Is there a way to break up the list of 74 strings into 74 separate strings to make the table/grid work?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `Prepend[SortedLat, {"", "B1", "B2"}]` what `TableOfValues2` should be? What is `q`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, The table is originally 74x2 without labels. Table of values 1 was actually what you wrote, since B1, B2 go on the top row of the table. Table of Values 2 is adding a column on the leftmost side of the table. q is just a list of 74 sublists, each sublist containing a pair of numbers.

Comment: Please provide also an example dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
TableOfValues2 = Join[Prepend[SortedLat[[All, {1}]], {""}], TableOfValues1, 2]
```